# jquery toggleclass fit with css hover effect

Tags: jquery, hover, toggleclass

I am new to jquery and trying to understand toggleClass function. I tried couples times myself and read some posts on SO but the effect still won't appear.

html:

```
<ul id="lists">
<li><a id="a" href="#">a</a></li>
<li><a id="b" href="#">b</a></li>
<li><a id="c" href="#">c</a></li>
<li><a id="d" href="#">d</a></li>
<li><a id="e" href="#">e</a></li>
</ul>
```

css:

```
#lists {
list-style-type: none;
}
#lists > li {
display: inline;
}
a:link, a:visited {
padding: 10px 20px;
text-decoration: none;
color: black;
background-color: red;
border: 4px solid white;
}
a:hover {
color: white;
}
.active {
background-color: green;
}
```

javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$("a#a, a#b, a#c, a#d, a#e").on("click", function () {
    $(this).toggleClass("active");
});
});
```

I have also make a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Wa4LZ/). What is wrong with my codes?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because your `:visited` overrides your `$.toggleClass`, you should do something like this:

CSS

```
a {
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    background-color: red;
    border: 4px solid white;
}
```

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Wa4LZ/4/)..

Comment: oh! thanks! just one minor question, how to highlight the current link when clicked?

Comment: What do you mean by highlighting ? Please be specific. Glad that I can help.

Comment: I modified my [Fiddle][1] and used addclass and removeclass. toggleclass is not working through.....I thought toggleclass is basically AddorRemove combine...? how do I work with toggleclass?

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/Wa4LZ/6/

Comment: Hmm.. Well, from your fiddle you need to change addclass and removeclass to toggleclass. Toggle will add the class if there isn't any, else it will remove it.